# Django: models backed by REST api

Tags: python, django, rest

I like the approach of [django-rest-models](https://pypi.org/project/django-rest-models/1.5.1/), but I am not sure it is production ready. I also worry that is not being actively developed anymore. In particular, it is not compatible to Django 1.11 (the latest compatible django is 1.10, which is [EOL](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/))

What is the standard approach to use REST APIs as models backend in Django?

Note: my question is **not** related to *building* REST APIs with django (for that we have DRF), but to *consuming* REST APIs and having the data available as standard django models.

Comment: you can use django models with class based views.

Comment: @jahmed31 The data is only accessible via a REST API. How can that be solved with class-based views?

Comment: kindly see the following link https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/02/03/how-to-use-restful-apis-with-django.html

these are with function views but if you got with class base views you can get more flexibility.

Comment: @jahmed31 thanks. I already read that blog post. That is not a *standard* approach, but a roll-your-own strategy. There is no abstraction to consume the REST Api and, moreover, there are no models backed by the REST Api, which is all I am asking: "How to back your models with a REST Api, ideally with a standard solution used by the django community?"